# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when only one constraint is set by Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I made a new project to practice iOS AutoLayout feature, **Visual Format Language**

I made only one button as below

```
var button:UIButton!
```

I made a method, which will add button to self.view, named initViews as below

```
func initViews() -> Void {

        button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.createConstraints()
    }
```

After this I created another method, as below for setting constraints.

```
func createConstraints () -> Void {

    //Views to add constraints to
    let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("button",button))

    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[button]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

//        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[button]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)

    //self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
}
```

Now, I am calling initViews in ViewDidLoad, but as it executed, it gives warning in LOG.

I am sure I can't see button without vertical constraint. but I am more conscious about warning.

**WARNING:**

```
2015-07-12 11:10:06.495 iOSAdvanceAutoLayout Project[1248:37226] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f062ffb0 UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.leading == UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f0630180 UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.trailing>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f056a820 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f056d0e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f0630180 UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.trailing>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-07-12 11:10:06.496 iOSAdvanceAutoLayout Project[1248:37226] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f062ffb0 UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.leading == UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f056c210 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.midX ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f056a820 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'(0)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f056d880 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0]   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fc9f061b9d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9f062ffb0 UIButton:0x7fc9f061ccd0'Button'.leading == UIView:0x7fc9f0572cb0.leadingMargin>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Can anyone guide me why this warning is there while only one constraint is set?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add following line after creating button

```
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also add vertical constraints, edit your method as following.

```
func createConstraints () -> Void {

        //Views to add constraints to
        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("button",button))

        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-30.0-[button]-30.0-|",
                                    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                    metrics: nil,
                                    views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)



        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-30.0-[button]-30.0-|",
                                    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                    metrics: nil,
                                    views: views)

        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
    }
```